# Why does my PC restart when trying to use a live CD and flash drive?

Tags: installation, usb, live-cd, compatibility, restart

Recently I was recommended Ubuntu 11.10 64-Bit. I burned the .ISO to a disc and verified it and went to boot it on my PC. When I selected it to boot on the disc, it would get to the menu. As I wanted to try it first, I selected that. My PC then got to the purple screen, went black, and then my PC will restart. So i have burned another CD to the same problem. I decided to try with a USB and i get the very same problem. my PC specs are:
Windows 7 64-Bit, 16 GB DDR3 RAM, Sapphire Radeon HD 7970 (21197-00-40G) 3072MB PCIe x16 Gen 3.0 Eyefinity 6 Edition.Is something wrong with compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

It would help knowing whether this a laptop or desktop If it's a laptop, it would be helpful to know what the laptop model is. If you've gotten to the purple screen that means you've gone past the BIOS meaning you're able to boot from CD/USB...I recommend selecting install Ubuntu instead of trying it in a live session and see what happens (selecting install Ubuntu will not format your HDD right away, you have to accept partitioning first, just wondering if it would let you install). Other work-arounds include installing to your hard drive in another computer, then putting it back into your machine.

Comment: It's a desktop computer. A Gateway 3X2370-UB3OP. It will only get to the purple screen if i boot from the GRUB menu. Also, this problems occurs when try to install, only when I do install, it says it's loading Casper, then restarts. I have not had this problem with Windows Vista and I have been told that this was supposedly a "Security Feature" that prevents boots from removable hardware.

Comment: Did it ever work? you might find the answer on this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1807580
Did you per chance try the install via Wubi?